# Cleaner output when downloading files in a Vagrant provisioning script

Tags: curl, vagrant, wget

I use [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com) for quickly bringing up test environments, development servers, etc. A lot of my Vagrant setups use [provisioning scripts](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html) to automate the download and configuration of various tools as necessary. However the "tricks" that command-line download utilities such as `curl` and `wget` use to generate their progress bars/status displays (backspacing to overwrite the current line of text to increment a progress bar, etc.) do not render well at all when run in a Vagrant provision script, and result in huge spews of junk such as the following that cause legitimate output to quickly scroll off.

```
==> default: #
==> default: #########
############                                                              16.7%
############                                                              16.7%
==> default: #
==> default: #
==> default: #
==> default: #
==> default: #
==> default: #
==> default: #
==> default: #
==> default: #
==> default: #
==> default: #
==> default: #
==> default:
==> default:
==> default:
############                                                              16.8%
```

Is there a way to "clean up" the output of either `curl` or `wget` to be neater, and not use the "backspace over current line to redraw it" tricks? I prefer `wget` but would switch to `curl` if necessary. Alternatively, is there another download tool with a simpler/neater output format that I could use instead? (preferably one available in Ubuntu's repository, as that is the distro I use with most of my Vagrant setups)

My current solution is to disable output entirely (using `wget`'s `--no-verbose` or `curl`'s `-s`) but this is not ideal as it results in long pauses where nothing is output during the vagrant build (some of the files that I download are rather large); it would be nice to at least have a simple "percent done" progress display, or even a simple line of "marching dots."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use `wget` with the `--progress=bar:force` option. While not ideal, this makes the outlook better. Without this option, `wget` defaults to the *dot* type progress bar, because it does not detect a terminal.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. The output becomes 

==> dendro: play-2.2.3.zip       52%[=========>          ]  56.51M  4.15MB/s    eta 19s

==> dendro: play-2.2.3.zip       53%[=========>          ]  57.27M  3.84MB/s    eta 19s